# formal process for troubleshooting CSS issues in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, code-inspection

Is there a way to see margin/padding/block boundaries in Internet Explorer code inspector, as Chrome has?

Troubleshooting a discrepancy in display between Chrome and IE is not easy when IE provides no visual aids in the view port when selecting elements in code inspector.

***Edit***: I've found the Layout tab on the right hand side of Dom Inspector in IE11, but I can't easily see what is causing the following discrepancy on [this page](https://www.orsgroup.com.au/all-states/nsw/);

Chrome:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]

Note the `Click Here` text is misplaced in IE?

I don't know a formal process for troubleshooting CSS issues in IE.

***Edit2***: I now see that the image behind the text `Click Here` is wider/taller in IE, which moves the dark blue box down, causing the text to display at the top of the dark blue box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F12, dom explorer, on right panel choose Disposition tab (the 3th) :)

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm using IE11. In Dom Explorer, I don't see Disposition in the right had side. What version of IE do you have?

Comment: Consider taking a screenshot too. :-)

Comment: IE 11 but present since IE 9 i think.

Comment: Ah ok. It is called `Layout` in my IE (`EN-AU` setting).

Comment: ah ah ok ^^ the main thing is that you found :) i tried to translate to you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Seem this solve the question, i have the same problem on my chrome and my IE11

```
.btn-4 p#more-btn {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 66px 7px !important;
}
```

Be warned the using of !important is not adviced.
Do you use a reset or equivalent for your CSS ?